# Permisison for SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS

Tags: database, db2

I'm new to DB2. I need to grant access to this table SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS.

```
db2 "select * from SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS"

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=ADMIN;SELECT;SYSIBMADM.MON_CURRENT_UOW, DRIVER=4.19.26
```

Do you know how I need to give permissions for this table?

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to match the query. And why do you get a Java exception from the DB2 CLP, which uses CLI/ODBC?

Comment: Cam you give some idea how I can give permissions to this table?

Comment: No, because your question doesn't make much sense to me. You should also mention your DB2 platform and version, after fixing the question.

Comment: Why do you need to grant access to it?

Comment: Because I need to get data from this table.